# Create a place holder for missing dates for different "start dates" in SPARK dataframe using PYSPARK

Tags: datetime, pyspark, missing-data, placeholder, fill

I have a dataframe which looks like this

| Account | Contract Number | Reading Start Date | City | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC123 | 19FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | 60115 |
| 123 | ABC123 | 20FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | 24621 |
| 123 | ABC123 | 22FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | 68816 |
| 567 | XYZ456 | 20FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | 71542 |
| 567 | XYZ456 | 21FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | 60115 |
| 567 | XYZ456 | 22FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | 24621 |

if you see the dates are missing in-between for contract number "ABC123" so I want to fill in the date in between and keep the value field null. Also fill forward the dates for all the contracts till 2 days before today. My desired output dataframe is like this (please note the first dates for account numbers are different)

| Account | Contract Number | Reading Start Date | City | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC123 | 19FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | 60115 |
| 123 | ABC123 | 20FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | 24621 |
| 123 | ABC123 | 21FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | Null |
| 123 | ABC123 | 22FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | 68816 |
| 123 | ABC123 | 23FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | Null |
| 567 | XYZ456 | 20FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | 71542 |
| 567 | XYZ456 | 21FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | 60115 |
| 567 | XYZ456 | 22FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | 24621 |
| 567 | XYZ456 | 23FEB2021:00:00:00.000000 | GREEN | Null |

I tried to do this in pandas with ffill and was succesfull. However I want to be able to do this in PYSPARK for distributed computing but I dont know how to do so. I tried various codes available on stackover flow but it does not work.

My PANDAS code is as per below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pandas_df,columns=['READING_START_DATE','CONTRACT_NUMBER'])
df.head()


from datetime import date
def expand_dates(ser):
    return pd.DataFrame({'READING_START_DATE': pd.date_range(ser['READING_START_DATE'].min(), date.today(), freq='D')})

newdf = df.groupby(['CONTRACT_NUMBER']).apply(expand_dates).reset_index()\
          .merge(df, how='left')[['CONTRACT_NUMBER', 'READING_START_DATE']].ffill()

dfmerge = pd.merge(newdf,pandas_df[['READING_START_DATE','CONTRACT_NUMBER','TOTAL_KWH']],on=('READING_START_DATE','CONTRACT_NUMBER'), how='left')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filling gaps in timeseries Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411184/filling-gaps-in-timeseries-spark)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert missing date rows and insert old values in the new rows PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59240277/insert-missing-date-rows-and-insert-old-values-in-the-new-rows-pyspark)